# Auto Send an Email on Date in Cell

Tags: google-apps-script

There is no bug in this code, but the code does not do any action.

I am making a code for when reading the date of the current day and relate to the date in a particular column, will send an automatic email.

```
function sendEmail() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName('Orçamento'))
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = 2;  // First row of data to process
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();   // Number of rows to process
  var numColumn = sheet.getLastColumn();

   // grab column 5 (the 'days left' column) 
   var data = sheet.getRange(2,6,lastRow-startRow+1,1 );
   var numRows = data.getNumRows();
   var date_values = data.getValues();

   // Now, grab the reminder name column
   data = sheet.getRange(2, 2, lastRow-startRow+1, 1);
   var reminder_info_values = data.getValues();

  //Logger.log(data)

for (i in data) {
  var column = data[i];
  var date = new Date();
  date.setHours(0);
  date.setMinutes(0);
  date.setSeconds(0);
  //Logger.log(date);
  var sheetDate = new Date(column[6]);
  //Logger.log(sheetDate);
  var Sdate = Utilities.formatDate(date,'GMT-0300','yyyy:MM:dd')
  var SsheetDate = Utilities.formatDate(sheetDate,'GMT-0300', 'yyyy:MM:dd')
   Logger.log(Sdate+' =? '+SsheetDate)
     if (Sdate == SsheetDate){
      var obra = column[1];       
      var descricao = column[2];       
      var inicio = column[6];       
      var fim = column[7];       
      var compra = column[8];       // Contact Method
      var subject = "Lembrete de início de Serviço: " +obra;
      var message = "O serviço: " + descricao + "tem previsão de data de início em " + inicio + "e previsão de término em : " + fim + "a previsão de compra do material é em: " + compra + ". Fique atento para não atrasar este serviço ";

      MailApp.sendEmail({
        to: "bruno@formula.eng.br",
        subject: subject,
        body: message,
      });
        }    
     }
    }
```

Comment: In your script, ``data`` is an object of range. You use "for in" for ``data``. By this, there are no errors at the for loop. And ``column[6]`` becomes ``undefined``. ``new Date(column[6])`` returns the value of ``new Date(0)``. So ``Sdate == SsheetDate`` always becomes ``false``. By this, the script in ``if`` doesn't run.

Comment: Thanks for help, I was able to adjust

Comment: Welcome. I'm glad your issue was solved.